# Regular expression for variables identificators

Tags: regex

There is a set of rules for identifiers (names) of variables:

1. It can include lower and upper letters, digits and the underscore character _;
2. It can only start with a letter or underscore;
3. If an identifier starts with the underscore, the second character must be a letter or digit, but not the underscore;

I wrote expression `[A-Za-z_][0-9A-Za-z_]{0,}` for 1 and 2 rules, but don't know what to do with 3 rule.

Comment: You may use `^(?:[A-Za-z]|_(?!_))\w*$` or ``\b(?:[A-Za-z]|_(?!_))\w*\b``

Answer (score 3):

You could use an alternation `|` starting with either an underscore or a char A-Za-z

```
^(?:_[A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Z-a-z])\w*$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `_[A-Za-z0-9]` Match `_` or any of A-Za-z0-9
  - `|` Or
  - `[A-Z-a-z]` Match a char A-Za-z
- `)` Close group
- `\w*` Match 0+ times a word char
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/P5eSfX/1)

Or using word boundaries

```
\b(?:_[A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Z-a-z])\w*\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/omQ5uO/1)

Answer (score -1):

Try with this: `^[A-Za-z_]\w*(?<!^__.*)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DqnIiq/20) here

Explaination:

- `^` -- means start of the string
- `[A-Za-z_]` -- means start with letter or _ only
- `\w*` -- means there can be occurs 0 or more word character(a-z,A-Z, 0-9 and _)
- `(?<!^__.*)` -- means can not start with __

Comment: Variable length negative lookbehind is not supported in all languages.