# String validation using regular expressions

Tags: c#, regex, validation

I need to create a regex for 3 rules.

1. The string can start with a letter or `_`. No numbers are allowed before the letter or `_`.
2. The `_` can be added in any place.
3. Using special characters or spaces is not allowed.

I created 2 regexes(`^[A-Za-z0-9_]*$` and `^[^0-9]*$`) but don't know how to combine them together. Also, the rules do not include a number at the end(like `_Sss12`).

```
_Aaa12 - correct
Aaa    - correct
aa aa  - fail
12aa   - fail
```

Comment: Sounds like you are verifying identifiers. Try [`^[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/UCL8wv/1).

Comment: @InSync Comments aren't for answers. Comments are for clarifying questions. If you have an answer, post it below in an answer.

Comment: @JeffC I know that. I'm finding a good target to VTC as dupe.

Comment: @InSync ...and yet you posted an answer in a comment.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [Regular expression to recognize variable declarations in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12993187) (the regex in the question itself), [Java Regular expression for checking validity of Variable name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23550455), [Regular expression for variables identificators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61539669).

Comment: @JeffC As a shortcut, yes, I did.

Comment: Maybe something like [`^(?!\d)\w+$`](https://regex101.com/r/Z7bqJK/1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see, you want to match an *identifier*, which

- **must** start from *letter* `A..Z`, `a..z` or `_`
- **can** contain *letters* `A..Z`, `a..z` or `_`, or *digits* `0..9`

If it's your case then the pattern can be

```
^[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*$
```

where

```
^             - anchor, start of the string
[A-Za-z_]     - Letter A..Z or a..z or symbol _
[A-Za-z0-9_]* - Zero or more letters, digits or _
$             - anchor, end of the string
```

If letters can be *any Unicode* letter, not necessary Latin ones, you can use `\p{L}` (for any Unicode digit, not necessary `0..9` `\d` can be used, but I doubt if you want Persian or Indian digits in the pattern):

```
^[\p{L}_][\p{L}0-9_]*$
```